# TextBox Added to Each Slide Actually Added Many to Each Slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am very new at vba and need some guidance please.  I am trying to add a text box to each slide (outside of the slide area), to view a slide's ID and Index at a quick glance.  I have pieced together several bits to create the code below.  it works, however the number of text boxes added to each slide is the number of slides in the presentation (112) instead of 1. I would also like to know how I can adapt this to be refreshed when changes to the slides are made.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
Sub AddSlideInfo()

'Original Source: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01180-Add-presentation-file-name-to-each-slide-master.htm

Dim x As Long
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oSl As Slide

With ActivePresentation

    On Error Resume Next 'In case the shape does not exist.

    ' On each slide in the presentation:
    For x = 1 To .Slides.Count

    Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(x)

        ' Create a textbox at 0" from left,
        ' -120.24 points from top of slide ( -1.67") from top left corner
        ' Make it 90 points high, 300 points wide 1.25" x 5.5"
        ' Change any of these numbers at will

        For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides

            With oSl

                Set oSh = .Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=0, Top:=-120, Width:=300, Height:=90)

                ' Give it a name so we can find it later
                oSh.Name = "SlideInfo"

                'Add some formatting and dummy text
                With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange

                    .Font.Name = "Berlin Sans Demi"
                    .Font.Size = 12
                    .Text = _
                    "Slide Info: " & vbNewLine & _
                    "Slide Index: " & oSl.SlideIndex & vbNewLine & _
                    "Slide ID: " & oSl.SlideID 


                End With

            End With

       Next

    Next x

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code loops though all the slides with the **For x = 1 To .Slides.Count** and then loops through all slides again with **For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides**. You don't need both.

The following is a simplified version of your code. It only loops through the slides once. It deletes the SlideInfo textbox if it exists (using On Error Resume Next to catch the error) ... but you can clean that up later :) ... and then recreates the textbox cleanly each time.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddSlideInfo()

    Const cShapeName = "SlideInfo"
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oSl As Slide

    On Error Resume Next

    With ActivePresentation
        For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
            With oSl

                .Shapes(cShapeName).Delete
                Set oSh = .Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=0, Top:=-120, Width:=300, Height:=90)
                oSh.Name = cShapeName

                'Add some formatting and dummy text
                With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
                        .Font.Name = "Berlin Sans Demi"
                        .Font.Size = 12
                        .Text = _
                        "Slide Info: " & vbNewLine & _
                        "Slide Index: " & oSl.SlideIndex & vbNewLine & _
                        "Slide ID: " & oSl.SlideID
                End With
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```